# Почему выдает null ? Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

У меня есть несколько сущностей, есть пост, его наследует VideoPost, у этого класса есть List с мелкими частями из которого будет состоять сам пост.

```
    public class Post : BaseId
    {
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Rating> Rating { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    }
    public class VideoPost : Post
    {
        public virtual List<VideoPostPart> VideoPostParts { get; set; }
    }

    public class PostPart : BaseId
    {
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
    public class VideoPostPart  : PostPart
    {
        public string VideoLink { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в меине выдает null при попытках получить эти самые частички поста

```
            db = new DataBaseContext();

            VideoPost post = new VideoPost();
            var user = new User();
            post.User = user;
            VideoPostPart part = new VideoPostPart();
            part.Post = post;
            part.VideoLink = "videolink";
            db.VideoPostParts.Add(part);
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var x = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault();
            var y = ((VideoPost)x).VideoPostParts; // y == null
```

Как мне сохранить данное наследование и сделать так, чтобы в сущности VideoPostParts Не создавался еще один внешний ключ в виде VideoPostId, Мне нужно чтобы внешний ключ был PostId, пробовал добавлять навигационное свойство в VideoPostPart с типом VideoPost и к нему добавлять аннотацию ForeignKey("PostId") Но так вылетают ексепшины и ничего не работает

Comment: А если бы вы это делали SQL запросами, то как бы по-вашему они выглядели?

Comment: Плохо sql знаю :)

Comment: В таком случае ORM вам мало чем поможет. Без понимания, как работает БД, очень сложно строить вменяемые запросы и структуры таблиц. Это даже со знанием SQL не просто. Я советую вам поизучать SQL, если вы планируете научиться работать с базами данных. По поводу вашего вопроса, вижу только что вы пытаетесь взять `VideoPostPart` не оттуда, куда ее положили, а совсем из другого места.

Comment: Для сущностей хранимых в БД вы напрасно используете наследование. Наследование ради экономии в написание повторяющихся свойств - негодное наследование.